# Give an example of an integral domain which has an infinite number of element yet its finite characteristics

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Give  an example  of an integral domain   which has an infinite  number  of element yet its  finite characteristics?

I thinks $\mathbb{Q}$

Is  it correct ??

Comment: No Q has infinite or 0 characteristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $F := \mathbb{F}_p(x)$, the field of rational functions in one variable over the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Or, just the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Comment: Yes; that should also work.

Comment: @Thanks u Ninja

Answer (score -1):

X is a set of infinity elements . Then P(x) is also infinity . And P(x) with respect to symmetric difference & intersection forms a infinite integral domain with Cher 2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).